# Tracing real-time filesystem calls by process?

Tags: filesystem, activity-monitor, macos

I suspect my backupd is performing a full filesystem scan. I can't tell because I don't know how to use Activity Monitor (or something else) to see what directories and files backupd is reading or writing. I'd like to check that and do it periodically so I can see if it's making progress.

Can someone suggest a program or command?

Comment: tmutil status - this command will allow you to see how many files and bytes it has counted. Not adding as answer because it doesn’t show you the files it’s checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was, ultimately, the best way I could find to do it:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep backupd
```

If I wanted to stop the flow:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep backupd | more
```

And if I wanted to output to a text file:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep backupd >output.txt
```

I largely found this information [here at AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/216329/trace-file-reads-and-writes-on-os-x/216330#216330). I then used the manpage for the command to piece together my commands above.

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: Can you please post where you found this?

Comment: I found some of it here and extrapolated from there. I didn’t find a single “here’s how ya do it” source.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Maybe be helpful to add links to other answers.

Comment: @Josh I tried to find the original URL from here but couldn’t. I will come back when I have it.

Comment: @Josh I didn’t but have now.